# How can I open 2 port on Create-React-App application, 1 for HTTP and 1 for HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, http, npm, https, create-react-app

Currently, I am doing a project made by React with Create-React-App.

As I read from some sources on the internet, Create-React-App just open 1 unique PORT.

We now wonder whether we can open 2 different ports for our React web application.

We looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

React is a frontend tool, it doesn't control any server aspects (ports being one of them).

So, if what you want is to serve a react app over SSL, you'll need to adjust that on your server, there's nothing about React in this case.

Now, what you've read is probably about react development server, if you want to modify its behavior, you'll need to eject the app & modify setting files (and change tags of the question from [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) to [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) to get help with this topic).